# Convincing my boss not to fire me

Tags: management, termination, performance

I've learned today that my boss is trying to replace me. From the echoes I got, I learned that he wants to do this because of an under-performance issue, my performance was not on point this year due to some personal reasons, now that I got back on track, and feel motivated to do the work, I would like to convince my boss not to do so, he didn't confront me to tell me why he'd like to replace me, nor to tell me that my performance was down.

I would like to talk with him to prove him that I can do the work. Please tell me what should I do and how I can convince him to change his mind.

By the way I've been working with this client for over 18 months as a contractor, and it is the cto (from my company) who told me he wants to end my contract.

Another note is that the candidate he had an interview with is a junior (6 months work experience) while I have 3 years experience now.

Thank you in advance

Comment: "my performance was not on point this year due to some personal reasons" May we ask what those personal reasons were? Does he know what they were? Are those one-time reasons? Or possibly recurring reasons? If you're just a contractor, you're probably very easy to replace. If I were you, I would try to jump ship before the final decision comes down. If you can jump ship right away, ~18 months is not bad to have on your resume.

Comment: Does you boss know your past performance was affected by your personal issues, and now you get over those issues, and are on track to perform well again ? If your boss does not know that, can you talk to him so that he can understand ?

Comment: If this rumor is serious, then you should start looking for a new job.  If your boss has decided you need to go, it is most likely too late to patch things up.

Comment: As a contractor, underperformance (meaning less output for the same cost) is always an issue. Is the issue here that you were available less time than originally planned (but still delivered the expected value per billed hour), or that your output per billed hour was unsatisfactory?

Answer (score 5):

A whole year of sub par performance is a bit much to explain away and that explanation should have been given long ago before it reached this state of affairs.

You can always try convincing your boss that things have changed, and it's not just because you're worried about being sacked, but be realistic and start looking for alternative employment.

Usually when they start looking for your replacement they won't stop looking and it's just a matter of time. Because that decision has already been made and invested in.

Comment: it wasn't a full year but let's say the second quarter, because prior to that, everything was fine.
Thank you anyways for your answer it is indeed very helpful

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to talk with him to prove him that I can do the work.

So talk to him.

Explain that you know your performance has been sub-par this year, but that you are now back on track and fully motivated. Point out that your performance prior to this year has been terrific (if that's actually the case). Ask for a chance to prove that you can do the job (talking won't prove anything, but your actions might).

It may not work, but at least you should give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

As a manager, if I have started looking to replace someone then I hate to say it but I am already past the point of talking with them to attempt to improve the situation. I will already have spent time attempting to discuss the situation with you and see what can be done to help. It we have got to the point where the process has started, no amount of talking now is likely to stop it.

However there is cause for hope! You have not been fired ***yet***. So put the effort in, do good work, show how valuable you can actually be to your organisation. Make yourself invaluable in the time you have available to you. Actions will speak far louder than words at this point. Make your manager notice you for good reasons, make your actions make them re-think their decision. It may not work, but for me this is your best shot.

Good luck!